# Device Tree Errors on ARM64 Ubuntu

Tags: kernel

I'm trying to enable the MIPI-DSI (display) interface on my Rockchip RK3399 (ARM64 arch) based board and I keep encountering the same error even after trying several things with the device tree. The OS is a fork of Ubuntu Bionic. Here is the [kernel](https://github.com/friendlyarm/kernel-rockchip).
Here is the error:

```
  [    1.195557] dw-mipi-dsi ff968000.dsi: can't request region for resource [mem 0xff968000-0xff96ffff]
  [    1.196387] dw-mipi-dsi: probe of ff968000.dsi failed with error -16
```

The error is `16 EBUSY`, but I'm not sure what that means. Here are the edits I made to the device tree:

```
 &dsi {
  status = "okay";
 };

&dsi1 {
   status = "okay";
};

&route_dsi {
   status="okay";
 };

 &dsi_in_vopl {
    status = "okay";
};
```

And here is the original DSI definition:

```
dsi: dsi@ff960000 {
     compatible = "rockchip,rk3399-mipi-dsi";
     reg = <0x0 0xff960000 0x0 0x8000>;
     interrupts = <GIC_SPI 45 IRQ_TYPE_LEreg = <0x0 0xff960000 0x0 0x8000>;VEL_HIGH 0>;
     clocks = <&cru SCLK_DPHY_PLL>, <&cru PCLK_MIPI_DSI0>,
          <&cru SCLK_DPHY_TX0_CFG>;
     clock-names = "ref", "pclk", "phy_cfg";
     power-domains = <&power RK3399_PD_VIO>;
     resets = <&cru SRST_P_MIPI_DSI0>;
     reset-names = "apb";
     rockchip,grf = <&grf>;
     status = "disabled";
     #address-cells = <1>;
     #size-cells = <0>;

    ports {
        port {
            #address-cells = <1>;
            #size-cells = <0>;

            dsi_in_vopb: endpoint@0 {
                reg = <0>;
                remote-endpoint = <&vopb_out_dsi>;
            };

            dsi_in_vopl: endpoint@1 {
                reg = <1>;
                remote-endpoint = <&vopl_out_dsi>;
            };
        };
    };
};
```

I think it has something to do with the fact that it's requesting the memory 0xff968000-0xff96ffff is being probed, but the interface is only 0x8000 wide. In other words, 0xff968000 + 0x8000 < 0xff96ffff, so it's probing memory it doesn't have access to. But the definition includes the interface size (`reg = <0x0 0xff960000 0x0 0x8000>;`), so I don't know how to debug this. These are the only changes I made to the tree, and these are the only relevant messages that show up in DSI.

Comment: How is it Ubuntu related?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out, it turns out that the DSI1 (the second DSI interface) overlapped with some other interface (I think CSI0) because it wasn't configured correctly. If you want to enable both, you have to disable one of the camera interfaces. In this case you can just disable DSI1 and more useful errors start showing up.